# Why is there an 'a' at the end of "Crimea"?

Tags: names

With the recent events in Crimea and the Ukraine the name of the peninsula appears a lot in both written and spoken, the *a* at the end is very conspicuous in the English pronunciation and writing, since there is no *a* in the Russian or Ukrainian name of the peninsula.
The name is *Крым* in [Russian](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC), and *Крим* in [Ukrainian](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2). It's clearly seen that the name ends with an *M* and is pronounced *Krim*.

According to an [article in the Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/worldviews/wp/2014/02/27/to-understand-crimea-take-a-look-back-at-its-complicated-history/) the name of the peninsula in the language of the local Crimean Tatar population is *Qırım*.

What is the source for the distortion of the name in English?

(Also, it seems that the same *a* appears in the [French](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crim%C3%A9e), [Spanish](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimea) and [Italian](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimea) name, and doesn't appear on the [German](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krim) name).

Comment: You have partially answered your own question: English is one of several languages which have an 'a' at the end of Crimea. It is quite likely that one or two started with it for phonetic reasons, and then others followed suit for consistency. But have you considered what word 'Crimea' would resemble in English if you left off the 'a', and (as in the Russian and Ukranian examples) did not pronounce a final vowel?

Comment: Good question, actually. The form _Crimea_ looks a lot like a Latin form, which makes sense with the other Romance forms. But why did Latin add _-ea_ to a word that originates in a Tatar word cited as _qırım_, with no final vowel at all? Surely _Crima_ (with no extraneous _-e-_ before the standard feminine ending) would have been a more obvious choice in Latin.

Comment: The (at least) Russian pronunciation of the name have a hard /i/ sound in it represented by the letter [*ы*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yery), so it doesn't sound like the word cream. And it didn't stop the English language to use words like ship and sheep, meat and meet, and dear and deer, so why start now?

Comment: "Ship" and "sheep" are very old examples which were part of the English language, likely well before anyone who spoke the language were aware of Krim; the homophones are similar. But in AmE, it's not a *ship* / *sheep* distinction: Crimea is pronounced /krajmia/, which when pronounced without the final vowels is just a /krajm/.

Comment: That *-ea* ending looks Romanian to me. Maybe the word came into Western languages (probably French) through Romanian and then spread into others, including English. But I have absolutely no proof of that.

Comment: The way a given language renders foreign place names is arbitrary.  In Latvian, it’s ‘Krima, krimas tatāri’ – a feminine noun with –a ending.  In Lithuanian, it’s ‘Krymas, krymo totoriai’ – a masculine noun with –as ending.  These forms reflect the typical pattern for city, country and other place names in each language.  Nothing significant can be concluded from this.

Comment: If you are going to regard every instance where the English name of a country is not the same as the name in its local language as a 'distortion', you are going to have a lot of straightening out to do. Just as regards our fellow members of the European Union alone, I can only think of one, namely France, where English gives it the same name as its native tongue(s).

Comment: @user2619, it is not arbitrary. Both the Latvian and Lithuanian forms, as you say, reflect typical naming patterns. The typical naming in Latin is either _-a_ or _-ia_, both forming feminines: _-ea_ is much, much rarer, especially with words of non-native (including Greek) origin.

Comment: @Janus: For place names ending with "ea", there's "Korea" and "Eritrea" (I don't think "Chelsea" counts).

Comment: @PeterShor, neither of those is Latin in origin, though. ‘Korea’ is much later than Latin, originally the name of a kingdom in Korea, as 高麗. Not sure how contemporary Korean would have pronounced that, but it’s [koɾjʌ] in Modern Korean, and the _-ea_ is a bastardised version of an attempt to express that in Western scripts. ‘Eritrea’ does come via Latin, but from Greek (_Ἐρυθρὴ Θάλασσα_) originally. In Greek loans such endings do occasionally occur in Latin, with Latin _-(a)ea_ here just an attempt at pigeonholing the Greek _-ē_ into a recognisable Latin adjectival paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

There was a vowel at the end, earlier too:

[Etymology of **Crimea**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimea#Etymology_of_the_name):

> Herodotus also refers to a nearby region called *Cremni* or 'the Cliffs', which may also refer to the Crimean peninsula, notable for its cliffs along what is otherwise a flat northern coastline of the Black Sea.

This *Cremni* seems closer to the present English *Crimea* than *Qırım* or the Russian *Krym*.

Comment: It is not closer, though, when you factor in that all the other Latin-derived names for the place have an _i_ in the first syllable and no trace of the _n_. I don't think _Cremni_ can be connected with the word _Crimea_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Is that an opinion?

Comment: No more so than the answer itself.

Comment: "I don't think Cremni can be connected with the word Crimea." Er, how about Eboracum, Eoforwic, and York? A few thousand years and drifting through a few languages can make some unexpected changes.